# How do I test a Signal R hub that has LifetimeScope injected into it

Tags: signalr, moq, autofac, xunit

How can I write unit tests to test my hub?

Here is my Hub Class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private readonly IMyProvider _provider;

    public MyHub(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        scope = _scope;
        _provider = _scope.Resolve<IMyProvider>();
    }

    public void BroadcastMessage(int messageId)
    {
        var myMessage = _provider.GetFromDb(messageId);
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(myMessage);
    }
}
```

I'm using moq and xunit, i've tried things like this:

```
//arrange
var messageId = 1;
var message = "test";
var providerMock = new Mock<IMyProvider>();
providerMock.Setup(x => x.GetFromDb(messageId).Returns(test);
var scopeMock = new Mock<ILifetimeScope>();
scopeMock.Setup(x => x.Resolve<IMyProvider>()).Returns(providerMock.Object);
var hub = new MyHub(scopeMock.Object);

//act
hub.BroadcastMessage(messageId);

//assert
providerMock.Verify(x => x.GetFromDb(messageId), Times.Once());
```

but this causes an error:

System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.Resolve()
    Extension methods (here: ResolutionExtensions.Resolve) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523868/3708225 that says I can do something like

```
using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()){
    var providerMock = new Mock<IMyPRovider>();
    providerMock.Setup(x=>x.GetFromDb(messageId)).Returns(message);
    mock.Provide(providerMock.Object);
    var lifetime = mock.Create<ILifetimeScope>();
    using (var scope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope()){
        var innerMockProvider = scope.Resolve<IMyProvider>();
        //rest of test
    }
}
```

but `AutoMock.GetLoose().Provide()` isn't defined

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for. But a workaround would be not to mock lifetimescope but simply setup a autofac container to use in these tests. 
Secondly do you need to inject the lifetimescope directly in your class? Maybe use a decorator pattern where you let the decorator create the lifetimescope and resolve your class and invoke it. Getting rid of the lifetimescope in your myhub class will make your life easier. Make it the job of some other class to control the lifetimescope. Else you will need to repeat this pattern in all your other classes as well. You should instead inject IMyProvider.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I am following Autofac/Signal R recommended guidelines here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html

Comment: that being said, I updated above for a different pattern, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this:

If I change my hub to the following:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{

    private readonly <Func>IMyProvider _provider;

    public MyHub(<Func>IMyProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void BroadcastMessage(int messageId)
    {
        var provider = _provider();
        var myMessage = provider.GetFromDb(messageId);
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(myMessage);
    }
}
```

Now i can mock `Func<IMyProviider>` to return what I need and ignore the lifetime scope

Comment: It would be even more simple if you just injected IMyProvider. And got rid og the Func stuff

Comment: @ChristianJohansen Thanks for the comment.  I was running into an issue where MyProvider was a null reference -- there is subsequent code down the dependency chain that requires (not my call) us to manage the lifetime dependency of our supporting signal r objects, so everything injected to the hub or the chain are flagged with .ExternallyOwned() in my registration